# How to sort a group of 4 columns in google sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

Is there a way to sort like this:

1. In column A:C will show the sorted data.
2. In column D:F(date,place,name)
3. In column H:I(date,place,name)
4. In column J:L(date,place,name)

What happens is that 2 to 4 will be sorted accending order and will be shown on 1... I only know in 1 set of columns but if there are 2 or more I can't seem to do it...

I'm using like =sort(D:F,1,true) how can I do it with 3 or more? =Sort(D:F,1,H:I,1,J:L,1,true)

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/105dwzLNB0dMWSKdXyVQHc-uhvpAn_qPvxkvxRP9z7HI/edit?usp=drivesdk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try in A1:

```
={D1:F1; SORT({D2:F; H2:J; L2:N}, 1, 1)}
```

[image]